# Hibernate query to get a list of objects, each desired object is inside a list of other objects. The list is part of another object

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am struggling from the morning with a query. I have the following JSON :

```
{
    "id": "87ee51c7-3f15-4772-a2fb-bee379e1054d",
    "description": "What color do you like?",
    "option1": "Yellow",
    "option2": "Blue",
    "option3": "Green",
    "option4": "Red",
    "option5": "Pink",
    "votes": [
      {
        "id": "26bf4e30-c75a-4267-8850-4f04101fdd35",
        "answerOption": "Pink",
        "user": {
          "id": "f836bd80-53d8-4623-8198-ca375abfdbbc",
          "authId": "auth0|5ff8fe4bee9af4febf00762c3f1e",
          "firstName": "Test",
          "lastName": "Name",
          "phone": "07545166181",
          "email": "user@yahoo.com",
          "buildingStreet": "test",
          "buildingNumber": "15",
          "buildingName": "8",
          "buildingEntrance": "A",
          "town": "town",
          "country": "country",
          "other": ""
        },
        "date": "2021-01-30"
      },
      {
        "id": "0047474f-ecf1-424b-960a-a512e6bb14f5",
        "answerOption": "Blue",
        "user": {
          "id": "7da77dff-a22a-47ac-b995-41fa90866016",
          "authId": "auth0|60055f048ec4a3006ee36d64",
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "phone": "0755888999",
          "email": "user2@yahoo.com",
          "buildingStreet": "street",
          "buildingNumber": "15",
          "buildingName": "8",
          "buildingEntrance": "A",
          "town": "town",
          "country": "country",
          "other": ""
        },
        "date": "2021-01-30"
      }
    ],
    "status": "active",
    "endDate": "2021-02-05"
  }
```

So I have a Poll, with an id, description and 5 options to vote. The Poll has a list of votes, so i have multiple votes.
Each vote contains an answer, date and user.

Is there a query to build a list of users knowing the question id ?

The idea is to build this list of user who already vote so i restrict them to vote twice for the same Poll.

I am using Hibernate as ORM, Spring Boot for back and React for front.

List findAllUsers....where poll id is...

Is there a way to get there with a statement ? Lately I am using Hibernate and I am very rusty with handmade queries.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use Spring Data JPA? How do the Java entities looks like? Do you use Spring Data (JPA) repositories?

Comment: Yes Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Repositories.

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "poll", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Vote> votes = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "poll_id")
    @JsonBackReference()
    private Poll poll;

Comment: User entity is not containing a list of votes or polls, if this is what you are wondering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data structure looks nearly like this:

```
public class User {

  @Id private Long id;
  
  // getters & setters

}

public class Vote {

  @Id private Long id;
  
  @ManyToOne private Poll poll;
  
  @ManyToOne private User user;
  
  // getters & setters

}

public class Poll {

  @OneToMany List<Vote> votes;
  
  // getters & setters
  
}
```

---

Using repositories, IMHO the cleanest place where to specify would be the `VoteRepository`. For that, the repository should look like this (using query generation with method names, see [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) in Spring Data JPA Reference Guide):

```
public interface VoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Vote> {

  List<Vote> findByPoll(Poll poll);

}
```

Then, to get all the users related to a poll, e. g. in a controller, mapping from votes to users should be done:

```
@Autowired
VoteRepository voteRepository;

public List<User> getUsersRelatedToPoll(Poll poll) {
  List<Vote> votes = voteRepository.findByPoll(poll);
  return votes.stream().map(Vote::getUser).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Another way, IMHO not the cleanest way (^1), could be a `@Query` method (see [Using `@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) in Spring Data JPA Reference Guide). This method would look like this:

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo> {

  @Query("SELECT v.user FROM VOTE as v WHERE v.poll = :poll")
  List<User> findUsersByPoll(@Param("poll") Poll poll);

}
```

^1: I think, e. g. in the `UserRepository` should not know about or use `Poll` or `Vote` ...